# Разбить строку по словам через запятую

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть переменная

```
$slova = "Рыба, Кот, Мышка, Дом";
```

Каким образом мне получить каждое слово отдельно и занести его в базу данных, таблица **slova** , чтоб получилось примерно так(в базе):

```
id 1 | name Рыба

id 2 | name Кот

id 3 | name Мышка

id 4 | name Дом
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь и любую полезную информацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$slova = "Рыба, Кот, Мышка, Дом";
$arr = explode(',', $slova);

foreach ($arr as $word) {
    $word = trim($word);

    // Конечно лучше использовать подготовленные запросы, но для теста вот.
    // При условии, что поле `id` является AUTO_INCREMEMT 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `slova`(name) VALUES('$word')";
    $insert = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая функция как [explode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php). И решение довольно простое

```
$slova = "Рыба, Кот, Мышка, Дом";

$slovo = [];

$slovo = explode(',', $slova);

print_r($slovo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нет явных разделителей, то можно по другому, например, если разбить по пробелам:

```
$toktext = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $text);
```